# NodeJs using express and pg-promise for postgresql?

Tags: sql, node.js, pg-promise

I'm running NodeJS and pg-promise, and are trying to accomplish somethings like:

```
db.any('SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE email=$1 NOT(SELECT email FROM t_user WHERE id= $2)', [email, id])

[and error syntax 'NOT'][1]
```

how i can `SELECT` with `WHERE NOT`?

Comment: `pg-promise` has no relevance here. Your query is invalid, and the error is server-side.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this.

```
db.any('SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE email=$1 AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT email FROM t_user WHERE id= $2)', [email, id])
```